# Converting Tensorflow 1.1 model into Tensorflow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to convert my tensorflow 1.1 based model into tensorflow lite in order to serve the model locally and remotely for a PWA. The [official guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) only offers Python APIs for 1.11 at the earliest. Command line tools only seem to work starting at 1.7. Is it possible to convert a 1.1 model to tensorflow lite? Has anyone had experience with this?

The tf module is an out-of-the-box pre-trained model using [BIDAF](https://github.com/allenai/bi-att-flow/tree/dev-demo). I am having difficulty serving the full tf app on Heroku, which is unable to run it. I would like to try a tf lite app to see if hosting it locally will make it faster, and easier to set up as a PWA.

Comment: TensorFlow 1.1 was released early 2017. You might want to update your code/model to a recent version. TF Lite should then work out of the box, and it will be easier to get help with issues. Mayne your Heroku problem with full Tensorflow has been solved even...

Comment: Unfortunately, the model that I am using is only verified under 1.1 and I do not know how to build or modify a tensorflow model, especially a complex one. I am hoping to see if anyone has had any success (or failures) converting any tf model under 1.11 to tf lite.

Comment: In many cases the 1.1 model should load without changes in Tensorflow 1.11. If this does not work you can open a new question about any errors you get